# How do the Armadans distinguish the Lovers in spoken language?

Tags: china-mieville, the-scar

In *The Scar,* China Miéville uses “the Lover” to refer to either Lover and only through his choice of pronoun it becomes (most often) clear whether he is referring to the male or female lover. Now, Armadans seem to refer to either of the Lovers in the same indiscriminate way, for example in this quote from near the end of the novel (potential spoiler):

> ‘Turn!’ shouted Tanner Sack. ‘We *turn* the city! **Get the Lover!** Get someone who knows how.’

Obviously, this way of communication can lead to confusion, so it seems likely that the Armadans have devised some way of discerning which Lover they are talking about.

Thus I am asking: Is there some clarification or hint in the book (that I missed) how the Armadans tell the Lovers apart when talking about them? For example:

- One of them /ðəˈlʌvə/ (regular *the*) and one of them /ˈðiːˌlʌvə/ (emphasised *the,* like *thee*).
- Salt has gender-specific words for *lover* that allow for a distinction.
- Armadans have developed a magic sense which Lover is meant (like [Discworld igors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Igor_(Discworld)) who always know to which Igor you are referring).